# UML Class Diagram - abstract or interface?

Tags: interface, uml, abstract-class, class-diagram

How can I know if class A is an interface, an abstract class or a concrete class (super class)?

[image]
According to answers, there are no direct instances of A so I assume that is an abstract class.

---

However, in this second image :

[image]

B should also be an abstract, if the first theory is right... but it can't because in the last answer there are direct instances of B class.

Answer (score 1):

If A would be abstract in image1 it would be shown with the name in italics and/or the string `{abstract}` next to it. This is not the case here. Therefore A *can* have direct instances. I guess there is a mistake in image1.

Please note that even if B in image2 would be abstract, it is meaningful to *specify* an instance of B. An instance specification *is not* an instance, and as such can be incomplete and abstract. An object will have complete features and a concrete class. For example I could have a red `Basketball`. In the model I might have an instance specification classified by `Ball{abstract}` and without a slot for the color, because I don't care which type and color it is. So any *instance* of `Basketball` or `Handball` will fit this instance *specification*.

Comment: Isn’t {abstract} and italic optional? (see my coment on ister’s answer)

Comment: @Christophe The sentence says "**is** shown in italics", not "**may** be shown in italics". The exception for fonts that don't support italics is strange. Which fonts currently in use don't support them? For me that still doesn't make it optional. It's more like, "_if you really have to use a crappy tool, don't worry too much about italics_". I read between the lines, that the second sentence was supposed to mean, that in this case the textual annotation is to be used.

Comment: Rereading it again, it still appears softer than expected: is not “is shown … except …” but “is show … where permitted” and there is no rule about what “permitted” really means.  The issue is that even if I’d agree with you, the ways this is specified leaves room for interpretation and you cannot avoid that someone could interpret it in a more relaxed way imho.

Answer (score 1):

As per UML specification, Section 9.2.3.2:

> The isAbstract property of Classifier, when true, specifies that the Classifier is abstract, i.e., has no direct instances: every instance of the abstract Classifier shall be an instance of one of its specializations.

The notation is described a bit further, in Section 9.2.4.1:

> The name of an abstract Classifier is shown in italics, where permitted by the font in use. Alternatively or in addition, an abstract Classifier may be shown using the textual annotation {abstract} after or below its name.

Neither of the two is indicated in the first diagram, so the answer is simply erroneous.

Note, one more indirect indication of the abstract class (though it is not directly mentioned, just comes from the general description) could be using a Generalization Set. There are a couple of notations used here, you can read about them in Section 9.7.4 (the entire Section 9.7 is about Generalization Sets). This notation also isn't used so still - there is nothing to indicate class `A` is abstract.

Comment: I agree that the answers are obviously misleading. However the notation does not oblige you to disclose abstractness of a class. In specification speak MAY indicates a possibility and MUST an obligation. “alternatively or in addition is an optional notation, exactly as “italic where permitted by font use”

Comment: (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119 : the UML specs do not refer to this explicitly, but in section 5.1 it refers to an ISO guidance which has exactly the same convention)

Comment: I think it does oblige you. See my comment on my answer.

Comment: Well, based on the diagram provided by OP there is no information enforcing abstraction thus the informative that class A *is* abstract cannot be derived from it. I didn't say A isn't abstract for sure, just that there is nothing to indicate that in the diagram so it should not be assumed to a level allowing to pick the answer that is based on abstraction of A.

Answer (score 1):

### First diagram

You cannot deduct from the diagram if `A` is an interface, an abstract class or a concrete class:

- `A` could be a concrete class that is further specialized by `B` and `C`
- `A` could be an abstract class and `B` and `C` be abstract or concrete specializations.  One would expect *`A`* to be in italic or followed with an `{abstract}` adornment, but these are not mandatory.
- `A` could even be an interface under some circumstances.  In this case, `B` and `C` would be specialized interfaces. This possibility has however a low probability because the `«interface»` keyword would be expected above `A`.  This notation was not mandatory in earlier UML 2 versions but the current UML 2.5 requires it (see Axel's comment).

So if the UML notation would be used with all possible accuracy, `A` would be a concrete class, but you can objectively not be 100% certain.

***Important note:** the provided answer claiming that "there is no instance for A" is hearsay.  No element in the diagram allows to draw this conclusion*

### Second diagram

We have seen that the answers to the first questions are flawed, and likewise, `B` is not necessarily an abstract class.

**Important revelation**:  you need to know that  `b : B` is possible even if `B` was abstract,  because in an object diagram you may chose arbitrarily to show membership to one class, event if the object would be more specialized:

> **UML 2.5 - Section 9.8.3**: An InstanceSpecification represents the **possible or actual** existence of instances in a modeled system and **completely or partially** describes those instances.

In case of doubt, a few lines later, you'll read:

> The InstanceSpecification may represent:
>  - Classification of the instance by one or more Classifiers, **any of which may be abstract**.

Keeping this in mind, the answers to the second diagram are all correct, whether B is abstract or not.

Comment: I think showing that something is an interface is not optional: "UML 2.5.1: _An Interface may be designated using the default notation for Classifier with the keyword «interface»._". The default notation says "_a keyword corresponding to the metaclass of the Classifier shall be shown in guillemets above the name._". There is another option to show Interfaces, but if you don't use it, the only defined notation is the default notation.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer I would anyway strongly recommend `«interface»`. But your reference is very interesting: It's confusing having a notation apparently optional in one place but mandatory in the other place.  In UML 2.5 my third bullet would then be eliminated.  However the narrative says UML2, and UML2.0/superstructure does not have a wording with a default notation: "As a classifier, an interface **may** be shown using a rectangle symbol with the keyword «interface» preceding the name".

Comment: @AxelScheithauer I've slightly edited the third bullet to reflect this exchange. Thanks for the last reference.